# Error:(27, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColor' with value '@color/link_text_material_light')

Tags: android

I am getting this error of no resource found and I don't know how to solve this issue can anyone help ?I am getting this error of no resource found and I don't know how to solve this issue can anyone help ?

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->











    <style name="CardViewLinkText">

        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dim_foreground_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="PujaDesc_CardView_Title">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/link_text_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_16_font</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PujaDesc_CardView_Desc">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/background_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_14_font</item>
    </style>

    <style name="book_puja_address_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="met_baseColor">#666</item>
        <item name="met_errorColor">#EE3233</item>
        <item name="met_floatingLabel">highlight</item>
        <item name="met_primaryColor">@color/primaryDark_orange</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CardViewDetailsText2">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dim_foreground_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">16dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PujaSuggHeadingText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDark_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_16_font</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PujaSuggDescText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_black_divider_60</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_14_font</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <string name="companyFounderTitle">Astro Techno Startup</string>
    <string name="ourCompanyTitle">Our Startup</string>
    <string name="ourPurposeTitle">Our Purpose</string>
    <string name="ourServicesTitle">Our Services</string>
    <string name="visitUs">Visit Us</string>

    <string name="web4"><a href="http://kundli.in/">kundli.io</a></string>
    <string name="web1"><a href="http://www.vedicrishi.in/">www.vedicrishi.in</a></string>
    <string name="web2"><a href="http://www.bookapanditji.com/">www.bookapanditji.com</a></string>
    <string name="web3"><a href="https://www.vedicrishiastro.com/">www.vedicrishiastro.com</a></string>

    <string name="companyFounder"> Pandit Rishiraj Tiwari, the Director of Vedic Rishi Astro Pvt Ltd, hails from the holy and
        ancient city of Varanasi, India - the land where rituals, religion and spiritualism all merge together for the benefit
        and salvation of mankind. Pandit Rishiraj Tiwari has vast, rich knowledge of Vedic Astrology and has been practising
        Astrology, Numerology and Vastu since past 25 years.</string>

    <string name="ourCompany">Vedic Rishi is an Astro-Techno start-up which aims to reorient the way people perceive and understand Vedic Astrology. \n kundli.io is a product of Vedic Rishi Astro. </string>

    <string name="ourPurpose">We strive to utilize the traditional and profound knowledge of Vedic Astrology and convert its principles and rules into a more precise language which will help in interpreting and analysing the complete range of human emotions, happenings and experiences, which will thereby facilitate in giving the most apt and relevant life trends and suggestions.</string>

    <string name="ourServices">kundli.io is a perfect place for you to prepare, read and store your complete astrological profile along with those of your family and friends. \n At kundli.io, we have taken great efforts to blend the powerful knowledge of ancient Vedic Astrology with latest technology to help, prepare and guide you for the upcoming excellent and not so happy events in your life. We have harmonized technical expertise with celestial rules of Astrology to create highly interactive and precise tools to give you the deepest possible analysis of your kundli i.e. horoscope.</string>
</resources>


build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.1'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

}
dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-android-support:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile files('libs/CleverTapSDKValidator-20151217.jar')
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vedicrishiastro.kundli"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "Beta 1.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/*apt {
    arguments {
        //androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        // If you're using flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
         resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}*/

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:2.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4'

    compile project(':multilevelexpindlistview')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'


}
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}


apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: do you have  color link_text_material_light defined? By error it is saying it is not able to find link_text_material_light color

Comment: @sankyjain yes in values.xml

Comment: can you show your values.xml file

Comment: @sankyjain ok wait i'll edit my question

Comment: @sankyjain <color name="primary_dark_material_dark">#ff000000</color>

Comment: @sankyjain <color name="link_text_material_light">@color/material_deep_teal_500</color>

Comment: how you defined material_deep_teal_500

Comment: <color name="material_deep_teal_500">#ff009688</color>

Comment: #ff009688 Hexcode ? I am not sure .Try with `<color name="material_deep_teal_500">#54D66A</color>`

Comment: try changing <color name="link_text_material_light">@color/material_deep_teal_500</color>  to  <color name="link_text_material_light">#ff009688</color>

Answer (score 1):

Did you define link_text_material_light in "values.xml" or "colors.xml"?

Try creating a file with "colors.xml" under values directory and define those colors in that file.

Comment: the problem is with gradle! i am getting a new error now cannot find APPcompact class